# .net 4.0 web.config unable to find assembly in GAC

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, web-config, gac

I've been playing around with the Jasig CAS module and wanted to add it to my webserver so that some websites can consume it if I  drop in the correct web.config settings.

I pulled down their .DLL and noticed it was not strongly named, so I pulled down their source and signed it.

Afterwards, I installed it into the GAC using gacutil and gacutil /l reports that it is correct.

However, when adding the assembly into the web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="DotNetCasClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f13867408864d7e" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

And then register the module, I am getting:
Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetCasClient' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The app pool that this test application is running has 32 bit enabled.  My machine is running IIS7 on win7 x64.

Anyone have any idea what I have done wrong or am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the DotNetCasClient using NuGet?

In the package manager you can use `PM> Install-Package DotNetCasClient`